# how to generate curves over coordinate axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, figure, curve, roc

I am looking to remake the following image in MATLAB:

[image: generic ROC curves]

Here's what I have so far:

[image: what I have so far]

I used this code to get what I have:

```
x = [0:.1:1];
y = [0:.1:1];
plot(x,y);
box off;
```

then I manually added an x axis label ("False Alarm Rate") and y axis label ("Hit Rate")

What I can't figure out is how to make the actual curves.
Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: that's a ROC curve. The curve is made by connecting the points of different tests and seeing how the ratio between Hits and False alarms behave depending on the parameters (in this case d)

Comment: yes, I know it's an ROC curve... I'm just attempting to make a generic one, like the one in the image for illustration purposes...can you be more specific/provide any code?

Comment: I can't see pictures. You can upload the pictures directly from Stackoverflow.

Comment: ok, I uploaded them!

Comment: What is the problem? What code have you used so far?

Comment: I added my code so far. The problem is I don't understand how to generate the curves (as in the first image) onto the coordinate axes in the image that I've built so far.